# Creating a non-square diagonal matrix from a vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, diagonal

I have a vector and I would like to have it repeated n-times forward and n-times backwards, but diagonally.

For example, I have the vector: 

`x= [0 0 1 1 0 0]`,

and would want a matrix of size 6x5 as follows:

```
1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1
```

This means that the vector `[0 0 1 1 0 0]` (transposed) is placed in the middle, and I would like a matrix such that when moving to the left, the elements are circularly shifted over to the top for each shift you make to the left.  Similarly, when moving to the right, the elements are circularly shifted down to the bottom for each shift you make to the right.  Therefore, the second column would be `[0 1 1 0 0 0]` where the elements are shifted to the left in a circular fashion once, then the first column would be `[1 1 0 0 0 0]` where we shift all elements to the left twice with respect to the middle and once with respect to the second column.

Similarly, the fourth column would be `[0 0 0 1 1 0]` meaning that with respect to the middle column, we shift all elements in a circular fashion to the right once, then the last column would be `[0 0 0 0 1 1]` where we shift all elements to the right twice with respect to the middle and once with respect to the fourth column.

Comment: Have a look at [`toeplitz`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html).

Comment: I see the pattern here, but what do you mean by repeat n-times forward and backward? Doesn't `spdiags` work?

Comment: I should mention that these matrices would be quite large , around 75000 x 201.

I have a vector of 201 datapoints of 0s with some 1s peppered in there. I'd like to extend it 100 backwards and 100 forwards in a diagonal pattern :)

Comment: Does the vector always have zeros except in the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the vector always consists of a nonzero part in the middle, you can use [`convmtx`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/convmtx.html) (from the Signal Processing Toolbox) as follows:

```
y = convmtx(nonzeros(x), numel(x)-1);
```

Or, if you don't have the Signal Processing Toolbox, use [`conv2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html):

```
y = conv2(eye(numel(x)-1), nonzeros(x)):
```

For `x = [0 0 1 1 0 0]`, either of the above produces:

```
y =
     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     1
```

Comment: The OP is expecting an output of size 6x5. Removing the last column and last row will do it!

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Thanks, I think I have corrected it. Although I fail to see how the output size is related to the input

Comment: Nicely done. I'm curious to see how `convmtx` benchmarks with my `mod/bsxfun` approach.

Comment: @rayryeng Very nice!

Comment: Now without `convmtx` @rayryeng

Answer (score 4):

`convmtx` requires the Signal Processing Toolbox in order to compute the result. Though Luis's answer is very good, may I suggest a method that doesn't rely on a toolbox?

```
n = 2;
ind = mod(bsxfun(@plus, (0:numel(x)-1).', n:-1:-n), numel(x)) + 1;
y = x(ind);
```

Or, if you don't want the intermediate variable:

```
n = 2;
y = x(mod(bsxfun(@plus, (0:numel(x)-1).', n:-1:-n), numel(x)) + 1);
```

For `x = [0 0 1 1 0 0];`, we get:

```
y =

     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     1
```

The explanation for this code is quite simple.  `n` denotes the number of times you would like to "repeat" the vector `x` to the left and to the right where each column circularly shifts the elements either upwards or downwards depending on which direction in the matrix you're headed.

The second line of code is the most daunting.  Let's start with the `bsxfun(...)` call:

```
bsxfun(@plus, (0:numel(x)-1).', n:-1:-n))
```

This creates a `numel(x) x (2*n + 1)` matrix where each column is simply the vector `(0:numel(x)-1)` but there is a constant value added to it.  Starting from the first column, we add `n` to `(0:numel(x)-1)`, then the second column we add `n-1` to `(0:numel(x)-1)` until we get to the middle which is simply `(0:numel(x)-1)` by itself.  After you pass the middle, we then **subtract** the vector with a constant, going from `-1` for the `n+1` column, `-2` for the `n+2` column until the end.  The result we get for `n = 2` is:

```
ans =

     2     1     0    -1    -2
     3     2     1     0    -1
     4     3     2     1     0
     5     4     3     2     1
     6     5     4     3     2
     7     6     5     4     3
```

In an ideal world, we would basically use this matrix to index into our vector to get exactly the matrix we want.  The columns to the left of the middle progressively access elements by specifying indices that are advanced by 1 and the result is to shift elements towards the top of the matrix. Similarly the columns to the right of the middle progressive access elements by specifying indices that are delayed by 1 and for result is to shift elements towards the bottom of the matrix.

Unfortunately, we have both negative values and values that exceed the length of the vector.  On top of this, MATLAB starts indexing at 1.  Therefore, you're going to have to use some wraparound logic to ensure that once we exceed the length of the vector or produce negative values for an index, we should wrap around to **1** instead of 0 or the length of the vector instead of -1.  As such, we can simply place a `mod` (modulus / remainder) operation bounded by the total number of elements in `x`, then after add 1 to the entire matrix so we can bound the indices between 1 and the total number of elements which now bring us to the completed second line of code:

```
>> ind = mod(bsxfun(@plus, (0:numel(x)-1).', n:-1:-n), numel(x)) + 1

ind =

     3     2     1     6     5
     4     3     2     1     6
     5     4     3     2     1
     6     5     4     3     2
     1     6     5     4     3
     2     1     6     5     4
```

The last step is to simply use this matrix to index into your vector to achieve the desired output matrix:

```
>> y = x(ind)

y =

     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     1
```

Comment: My gut feeling thinks that for performance we could use a zeros initialized array and then set values into it in a vectorized manner with something like `bsxfun(@plus` to get those linear indices, where those repeated values are to be put. I guess all this is worth if OP cares about performance.

Comment: @Divakar That's interesting.  I'll have to experiment with that but this is assuming of course that the `x` array has some zero values in the vector.  The way I did it would work if `x` was completely full too.

Comment: Ah hold on! I assumed we would always have an input vector with lots of zeros and some non-zeros! So, if that's not the case, the modding is probably the good way!

Comment: @Divakar Yes! I agree.  Perhaps a compromise between both methods may suffice... maybe if `n < 5`, then treat it as a sparse population of elements whereas if `n > 5` then do the `mod` way.

Comment: Yea yeah, for a sparsey vector, getting those linear indices and then setting those could be nicer.

Comment: @Divakar I'll have to experiment, but that is certainly a nice idea.  You're only accessing as many elements that are non-zero times the total number of columns in the matrix whereas my method it's `numel(x) x (2*n + 1)`.  The decreased number of accesses should give better performance... of course assuming that `x` is small in size.

Comment: This is great thanks so much. I truly appreciate how much detail you went into!

Comment: No problem at all @Neuraxis